# JQuery Syntax Problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery to insert divs into a page but i cant seem to get the quotation marks correctly setup.

For example the code below works fine:

```
var newDiv_1 = '<div id="event_1"><b>Hello World 01</b></div>'; 
$('#mon_Events').append(newDiv_1);
```

But when i try to use variable in place of the normal text, i doesnt seem to work:

```
var eventname = 1;
var newDiv_1 = '<div id="event_' . eventName . '"><b>Hello World 01</b></div>';
$('#mon_Events').append(newDiv_1);
```

How do i use variable inside this statement?

Comment: either I'm unaware of javascript operators or you need to change it to `+ eventName +`

Answer (score 2):

Your `eventName` is defined as `eventname`:

```
var eventName = 1;
var newDiv_1 = '<div id="event_'+ eventName +'"><b>Hello World 01</b></div>';
$('#mon_Events').append(newDiv_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have security concerns with HTML string slinging, you can do this:

```
var newDiv_1 = $("<div><b>Hello World 01</b></div>").attr('id', 'event_' + eventName);

newDiv_1.appendTo('#mon_Events');
```